# What fine-tuned word finders are out there?

Tags: discussion, resources

I know there's a lot of word finders, but I'm wondering if there is some this fine-tuned.

For example, if I want words ending in -ade, but only nouns.

accolade, charade, tirade, façade, balustrade...

I just now realized these words are probably French in origin. Blade, trade, cascade would fit.

So I guess the question is what is the best word finder out there? Guess there isn't one with so many filters, but if you're an entrepreneur here's an uncharted market niche haha

Answer (score 4):

[Visca.com's Regex Dictionary](https://www.visca.com/regexdict/) can do that. There are filters for each part of speech and you input a regex to match words. The regex for your particular search is `ade$`, where `$` makes it match the end of the line (i.e., the end of the word).

You can do some pretty complex searches if you know regex (admittedly, not many people do — it's complicated). For example, here's the regex to find words that start and end with the same letter: `^(.).*\1$`

Answer (score 3):

onelook.com purports to find all words ending in, say, ade, and the lets you make a second selection, e.g., common nouns.

This sounds like what you’re looking for.

There are some two-word results among the 134 that show up with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a tool exists that satisfies your requirements. You have described two filter criteria; suffix (ending) and 'word class' (noun, verb, adjective, adverb). Bear in mind that suffix often (though not always) denotes 'word class' so a [crossword solver](https://crossword-solver.io/) will get you some of the way there and the rest is 'wetware' (brain power).

As an idea for a general "word finder", the proven TAM ([total addressable market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_addressable_market)) is currently one person i.e you. You're going to have to spend time elaborating on requirements and potential uses before anyone might pick this up as an opportunity. As Einstein said "*Genius is 1% inspiration, 99% perspiration*".

Good luck with it.

Comment: Best answer ever! lol

Comment: https://www.english-corpora.org/corpora.asp

this one seems cool to explore